# When to use activities or fragments

Tags: android

My App (minimum API 14) uses an ActionBar with 3 tabs.
The tabs are:
i.   enter data  (approx 10 fragments)
ii.  manage data (15 fragments)
iii. view data   (8 fragments).
Each tab has a default fragment, but then has multiple fragments depending on user choices.

I would like the user to be able to swipe between the 3 tabs (by swiping the content) hence I need to use ViewPager and the compatibility library v4.

The advice I have picked up (after much research) is to use a MainActivity which hosts the ActionBar and tabs with fragments for the tab contents. But I'm worried about the number of fragments. Also some of the fragments need to use date and time pickers which means DialogFragments coming out of fragments. It's starting to get very complicated.

Does anyone see any problem with my using Activities instead of fragments for the tab contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments act on the UI side just like activities except you can combine multiple together. So you don't need to create a different fragment based on user choices, you just need to change the fragment just like how you would change an activity dynamically.

**Also if you want to use ViewPager, you are basically forced into using fragments.**

The nice thing about fragments is that they are reusable, so most likely you only need a few fragments and then you can combine them in different ways for the different use cases. This also makes your tablet UI a lot easier to create.

For reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea of changing the fragments. Not thought of that. Will have a lot of ui to do in code rather than using xml but I guess that should still work.

Comment: Trust me, it seems a lot harder than it is, I held off on fragments for far too long... also please remember to mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as I think I will need multiple fragments. For example, view data fragment1 will show a list of available reports, view data fragment2 will prompt the user for criteria for the first report, view data fragment3 will return the results, etc.

Comment: But this is the thing, you would have to do that anyway with activities and so really it's a win-win situation you lose nothing for going to fragments, but you gain increased flexibility... also please remember to mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)